# Python: RuntimeError: can't start new thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, resources

I was using resource library from python to limit my resources

```py
import resource


rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_DATA
resource.setrlimit(rsrc, (150*1024*1024, 200*1024*1024))
```

and I'm getting this issue while publishing the message saying that:

```py
Exception in thread Thread-PubSubBatchCommitter:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1010, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/client.py", line 454, in _wait_and_commit_sequencers
        self._commit_sequencers()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/client.py", line 468, in _commit_sequencers
        sequencer.commit()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/_sequencer/unordered_sequencer.py", line 80, in commit
        self._current_batch.commit()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/_batch/thread.py", line 217, in commit
        self._start_commit_thread()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/_batch/thread.py", line 227, in _start_commit_thread
        commit_thread.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 992, in start
        _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

I don't understand why am I getting `can't start new thread` Exception when I was limiting my resource I have tried increasing the hard limit the error remained same but when I have increased soft limit I didn't get the error

As of my understanding the error occurs when you have already have too many threads running within your python process, and due to a resource limit of some kind the request to create a new thread is refused.

i have tried using `mprofile` and the highest memory consumed was 68 Mib. Can someone explain me whats happening behind the hood?

Comment: `Import` should be `import`.

Comment: `resources` should be `resource`

Comment: . . . so it looks like there were two typos on the first line of code.

Comment: ignore them someone has requested for edit i forgot to check them

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same issue then search for **RLIMIT_DATA** and that should answer your question

> *This is the maximum size of the process's data segment (initialized data, uninitialized data, and heap). The limit is specified in bytes, and is rounded down to the system page size. This limit affects calls to brk(2), sbrk(2), and (since Linux 4.7) mmap(2), which fail with the error ENOMEM upon encountering the soft limit of this resource.*

https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/getrlimit.2.en.html

So the issue is that it is expected to raise an exception on reaching the soft limit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).